# behaviour of the option multicols in listings

Tags: listings, multicol, optional-arguments

I think the following two codes saying the same thing. However, the second code causes error.

My question is: how to make the second code workable same as what the first code does. That is to say, how to make the option `multicols` accept a value from a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,multicol}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Code 1:
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\begin{lstlisting}[multicols={},frame=single]
  aa bb
  cc dd
  ee
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

Code 2:
\def\aaa{}
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\begin{lstlisting}[multicols=\aaa,frame=single]
  aa bb
  cc dd
  ee
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the definition of the `multicols` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,multicol}

\makeatletter
% use \edef rather than \def
\lst@Key{multicols}{}{\@tempcnta=0#1\relax\edef\lst@multicols{#1}}
\makeatother

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
Code 1:

\begin{lstlisting}[multicols={},frame=single]
  aa bb
  cc dd
  ee
\end{lstlisting}

Code 2:
\def\aaa{}

\begin{lstlisting}[multicols=\aaa,frame=single]
  aa bb
  cc dd
  ee
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! And when `\def\aaa{1}`, the columns of typeset is still two not one.

Comment: @lyl That's how `multicol` works.

Comment: Many thanks again for your help to my question - so that `\def\aaa{}` and `multicols={}` can obtain the same effect of `multicols=1`!!!